# Number of free beds in a set date in a set department

Tags: sql, postgresql

my problem is this:
I have this tables:

Patient (fiscalcode, name, surname)
Department (id, name)
Bed (id, department) : department references Department(id)
Recover (patient, bed, start_date, end_date*) : patient ref Patient(fc) and bed ref Bed(id)

I need to make a query returning the number of occupied beds in a given date and in a given department d.

I was thinking of something like this, but i'm not sure:

```
SELECT count(bed.id)
FROM bed b
    ,department dep
    ,recover r
WHERE dep.id = d.id
    AND d.id = b.id
    AND r.bed = b.id
    AND r.start_date < given_date
    AND r.end_date < given_date
```

Comment: You can use Schema Deck to share your database tables, like this: http://schemadeck.com/ofcspr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work for you

```
SELECT COUNT(B.ID)
FROM BED B
    INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT D ON B.department = D.id
    INNER JOIN RECOVER R ON R.Bed = B.id
WHERE
    R.end_date < given_date
    AND R.start_date < given_date
    AND (D.name = 'department_name' 
         OR 
         D.id = --departmentID--
         )
```

You actually had an extra condition in your WHERE clause that required the `ID` in `DEPARTMENT` talbe to be the same as the `ID` in `BED` table.

Comment: Yeah that was a mistake, should have been d.id = b.dep, i got confused. Thanks a lot for the answer. I'm happy atleast I was close. I'm quite bad with SQL.

Comment: You understood the logic and made a decent query. You're on your way to becoming better, so good luck!